# With new in-app billing, com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED intent is no longer being sent

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

My Android app makes in-app purchase using the [OLD (V2) version of Android's in app billing architecture](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/api.html).  I am not able to update my clients to V3 just yet.  However, on some phones, a new "checkout experience" is now being shown during purchase -- the Google-provided dialog for purchasing an item has changed to a more modern look.  Which is fine, except that along with this change, a key part of the in-app purchase flow has stopped working, namely the sending of the com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED intent, which is vitally important.

Thinking I must be doing something wrong, I hunted down and found the [old sample app](http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/checkout) (Dungeons) that is illustrates the use of the old V2 in-app purchase API.  Sure enough, this sample also fails to complete the purchase, because Android (with the new fancier in-app purchase dialog) is no longer sending that intent.

Has anyone else seen their old V2 in-app purchase flow break, and found a way to work around it?

I would love to attach images of the way the in-app-purchase dialog looks on an old phone (where the Dungeons sample succeeds to make a purchase) and a new phone (where Dungeons fails due to the lack of the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED intent).  Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation on Stack Overflow to post links to the images.

Thanks!

Greg